# Android App that communicates with a Java Program on a PC

Tags: android, android-wifi

Where would I start if I want to create an Android App that communicates with a Java Program on a PC through WiFi. What I am actually trying to achieve is I wanna make a Wifi Doorbell System. Install the Android App on the phone, Install the Java App on the PC. I just wanna ring the Java App using the Android phone.

I have only started learning developing Android apps. I only know the basics such as using TextView, EditText, and Spinners. I think the android.net.wifi is going to be on a different level though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to code kind of network server to the pc using java, and then code a client that talks to that server in android. Using some kind of protocol you can send various commands to the server to execute locally to the pc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need worry about wifi, if both the phone and the pc are on the local network, you would just have the java app listen on a particular port, and the phone app would send messages to the pc's ip address on that port.

That's the high level answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (may be) is to make every android devices recognizable on the network, and send a datagram message to every devices on the LAN

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate?